# Iris-Data - regplot out of dataframe -> choosing color

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

Problem:My dataframe contains of the Iris-Dataset and looks like this:

[image]

It has 50 entries of 3 species each, making 150 in total.
Now I want to display the 4 attributes in a regplot and distinguish the 3 types with colors.

My code for that part looks like this:

```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
   import seaborn as sns

   plt.figure(1 , figsize = (15 , 7))
   n = 0 

   colors = {'Iris-setosa': 'red', 'Iris-versicolor': 'blue', 'Iris-virginica': 'green'}

   sns.set(color_codes=True)

   for x in ['sepal-length' , 'sepal-width' , 'petal-length', 'petal-width']: 
     for y in ['sepal-length' , 'sepal-width' , 'petal-length', 'petal-width']: 
       n += 1
       plt.subplot(4,4,n)
       plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.5 , wspace = 0.5)
       sns.regplot(x=x, y=y, data=df, color=???, line_kws={"color": "green"});
    plt.show()
```

Where one can determine the color, I get no further. I want the color from the respective column to be used for the species. So setosa = red, versicolor = blue and virginica = green. I would be glad if somebody could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the colors following [this link](https://python-graph-gallery.com/45-control-color-of-each-marker-seaborn/). Since they are fixed, then a easier solution without plotting twice:

```
colors = {'Iris-setosa': 'red', 'Iris-versicolor': 'blue', 'Iris-virginica': 'green'}
scatter_col = [colors[i] for i in df['species']]
g = sns.PairGrid(df,height=3, aspect=1.5)
g = g.map(sns.regplot,line_kws={"color": "green"},scatter_kws={'facecolors':scatter_col})
```

[image]

Comment: Thats perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could first call the regression plot without plotting the individual points (`scatter=False`) and then loop through the species, adding a scatter plot for each. In this way, you can look up the color in the dictionary for each scatter plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(color_codes=True)

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
colors = {'setosa': 'red', 'versicolor': 'blue', 'virginica': 'green'}

plt.figure(1 , figsize = (15 , 7))
n = 0 
for x in ['sepal_length' , 'sepal_width' , 'petal_length', 'petal_width']: 
    for y in ['sepal_length' , 'sepal_width' , 'petal_length', 'petal_width']: 
        n += 1
        plt.subplot(4,4,n)
        plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.5 , wspace = 0.5)

        sns.regplot(x=x, y=y, data=df, line_kws={"color": "green"}, 
                    scatter=False) 
        for spec in set(df.species):
            sns.scatterplot(x=x, y=y, data=df[df.species == spec], 
                            color=colors[spec]);
```

[image: Iris plots]